# conky-all says it's installing cairo but lua can't find cairo anywhere

Tags: kde, conky, cairo, lua

I've been trying to get conky to work for awhile now, but I can't seem to make it install cairo properly.

What I've done:

- installed conky-all (`sudo apt-get install conky-all`)
- Tried to get a theme which used lua and cairo, but that didn't work, because conky couldn't find cairo
- I opened up a lua command line (`lua`) and tried the command `require 'cairo'`. I got this:

```
no field package.preload['cairo']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/cairo.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/cairo/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/cairo.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/cairo/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/cairo.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/cairo/init.lua'
    no file './cairo.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/cairo.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/cairo.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/cairo.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './cairo.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I ran `conky -v`, and it told a different story:

```
Lua bindings:
  * Cairo
  * Imlib2
  * RSVG
```

Does anyone know how to 'correctly' install cairo or get lua to find it? I just want conky to work ;(

Comment: I am having the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767863/lua-cannot-open-libcairo-with-error-undefined-symbol-luaopen-libcairo), from what ive been told, it seems that it might help to build conky from source ensuring that the BUILD_LUA_CAIRO flag is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

conky only provides the cairo and imlib2 binding internally, they won't work in your external lua installation.
Additionally, the conky from [extra] is only compiled with imlib2, so you should use that. If you really want cairo, then you'll have to recompile it with cairo enabled.